# Whats the best way to level up many shipgirls?

Tags: kantai-collection

If the last event taught me anything, it's that your entire fleet needs to be strong. not just the 6 or so favorites in your main fleet.

So, to kind of prepare for the next event I want to get as many shipgirls as I can up to their kai or kai ni versions. What's the best way to go about this?

I am currently just spamming 3-2A with a submarine to tank the damage so we don't repair much, but that still takes a pretty long time. It also is pretty draining on my resources for resupply every few minutes.

Are there expeditions that offer better exp that I can send a group while spamming 3-2A, or ways to 'boost' exp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few ways to collect xp depending on your goals and your ship types.

For Expeditions, you are talking about Expedition 32. It requires a training cruiser and will give a varying amount of xp depending on the ships level and the training cruisers level. [The wiki](http://kancolle.wikia.com/wiki/Expedition_32) has formulas but it generally boils down to the higher te level of the CT flagship and the lower the level of the ship(s) you want to train, the more xp.

Alternatives to 3-2A are for DD/CL map 4-3. (copy pasted info from the wiki again)

1. Put your DD/CL as flagship and give her all ASW equipment to ensure that she can get MVP at every SS node.
2. A fleet with 0-1 DD, and 0-1 CA will almost always let you reach two SS nodes (F->K or F->D)
3. 1 DD/CL + 1 BB + 2 CVL + 1 CLT + 1 SS
4. When starting, you may go to Node J before moving to Node F. If RNG brings you to Node J, use Line Ahead formation to allow your BB/CVL/CLT to kill enemy's BB/CAs or disable their CV as soon as possible. Defensive formations are almost useless.
5. When you hit the two SS nodes, use Line Abreast formation to maximize your damage on the enemy submarines. CVL can also help with ASW. Getting MVP in these 2 nodes allows your flagship to stay sparkling all the time, and you can farm non-stop as long as you can provide ships for other positions. End the sortie after the two SS nodes.
6. Be aware, never take 2DD or 2CA, they will branch you the wrong ways.
7. Be sure to stop at K. at D, there is a chance to go to the Bauxite resource node, i personally risk it and press on. sometimes i have to fight at node G then.

If you have access to 5-4, you can use this to train either similar to 3-2A or to try to go for a ranking spot (aprox 20 runs/day). The type of enemies is harder then at 3-2 though and the enemy CAs will ignore subs. If you try the ranking option, you can quickly level any fast ship, just give it flagship position. (if it can equip drums, use it as a drum carrier)

Finally, i use PVP alot for leveling ships. Even if you take a loss, it will give a large amount of xp for the effort

PS: For the desperate and resource rich.

Expedition 22 and 23

22 requires 1CA 1CL 2DD 2XX and uses the same ammo/fuel as 4 battles (aprox.)
it gives 400xp and takes three hours. (flagship level 30+, total level of all ships combined 45+)

23 requires 2BBV 2DD 2XX, grants you 100bauxite but still uses 4 battles of fuel and ammo, gives 420xp and take 4 hours.(flagship level 50+, total level of ships 200+)

1 run on 3-2A gives 320xp, +10% if you S rank it and a double bonus for the MVP. and takes a minute or 3. I don't think anyone runs these 2 but if you are running 3-2A and these two expeditions, well, your wasting resources more because your not running 2,5,6

Comment: OK, I don't have a CT(RNG-Sama is the worst), and I only have up to 3-2 unlocked. options?

Comment: @3-2A will be the best xp, although with the new pre emptive ASW, you could train DD and CL in 1-5. You'll either need Isuzu Kai Ni or a high level CL/DD you can get past 100ASW to improve the issues with first node. There is no boosts or better maps to run, and unless your really depserate for xp and have spare resources, no expeditions.

Comment: alright, I'll keep throwing resources at construction in hopes of Katori, I'll spend a little bit of time to actually clear 3-2 and unlock the other areas too. thanks